# Увеличение масштаба изображения в Photoshop

Tags: изображения, дизайн, photoshop, обработка-изображений, рисование

1. Как увеличить изображение в фотошопе (с помощью каких пунктов меню и горячих клавиш)?
2. Как отменить выделение магнитного лассо, если контур полностью и окончательно не выделен? (доступа к пунктам меню нет - пока контур не замкнут)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не по теме.

Comment: @eanmos что не по теме?

Comment: Вопрос никак не связан с программированием или системным администрированием, поэтому и не по теме. Этому вопросу место на https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Лупа. Клавиша `Z`
2. Два раза кликните в одном месте и тогда выделение закончиться. Чтобы снять выделение нажмите сочетание клавиш `Ctrl + D`